# Relative path not working with named volumes in the docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I need to make a named volume use a relative path to the folder where the `docker-compose` command is executed.

Here is the volume definition in the docker-compose.yml

```
volumes:
  esdata1:
   driver: local 
   driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: ./esdata1
      o: bind
```

It seems that [docker-compose do not create the folder if it does not exist](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/19990#issuecomment-248955005), but even when the folder is created before lauching docker I'm always getting this error:

```
ERROR: for esdata  Cannot create container for service esdata: error while mounting volume with options: type='none' device='./esdata1' o='bind': no such file or directory
```

**NOTE:** This is maybe silly, but `esdata` is the service that use the named volume

```
  esdata:
    ...
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ...
```

What I'm missing here?

Maybe the relative path `./` does not point to the folder where the `docker-compose` is executed (I've tried with `~/` to use a folder relative the user's home but I got the same error).

Thanks in advance,

PS: If I use an absolute path it works like a charm

Comment: have you try as sudo? sudo docker-comose ?

Comment: I just tried. Nothing. Can you please share why did you though `sudo` might help?

Comment: well... perhaps was a problem of permission... expecially if is MacOs

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the relative path instead of a named volume in the service definition?

Comment: To reuse the volume on several services only.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered exactly the same issue. It seems that you have done nothing wrong. This is just not yet implemented in Docker : https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6343

Not very nice for portability...

Answer (score 2):

If you use a named bind mount like this, you must include the full path to the file, e.g.:

```
volumes:
  esdata1:
   driver: local 
   driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /home/username/project/esdata1
      o: bind
```

That folder must also exist in advance. This is how the linux bind mount syscall works, and when you pass flags like this, you are talking directly to Linux without any path expansion by docker or compose.

If you just want to mount the directory from the host, using a host volume will be expanded for the relative path by compose:

```
  esdata:
    ...
    volumes:
      - ./esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ...
```

While the host volume is easier for portability since the path is automatically expanded, you will lose the feature from named volumes where docker initializes an empty named volume with the image contents (including file permissions/ownership).