# Relative Path with Docker-Compose Shared Volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

It seems [this question has already been asked by another poster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42961256/relative-path-not-working-with-named-volumes-in-the-docker-compose-yml), but there was no answer.  I have more information on the matter, so I'm re-asking the same question - but with much additional material.

I'm running Docker on Windows 10.  I have Docker configured for using Linux containers (not Windows containers).  I have my C drive configured as a shared drive.

### The Problem

I have the following docker-compose file called `wp.yml`:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - type: volume
         source: wp_dbA
         target: /var/lib/mysql       
     restart: always

volumes:
    wp_dbA:
      driver_opts:
        type: none
        device: ./wp-db
        o: bind
```

I execute as follows:

```
c:\repos\wpsand\wpA> docker-compose -f wp.yml up -d
```

I receive the following error:

> ERROR: for wpa_db_1  Cannot create container for service db: error while mounting volume with options: type='none' device='./wp-db' o='bind': no such file or directory
>
> ERROR: for db  Cannot create container for service db: error while mounting volume with options: type='none' device='./wp-db' o='bind': no such file or directory
>   ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

Despite the message,the folder `wp-db` does already exist, located here:

```
c:/repos/wpsand/wpA/wp-db
```

### Clues...

Despite the above error, checking `docker volume ls` reveals that volume `wpa_wp_dbA` was freshly created.

Clue #1

If I change the shared volume `device` to use an absolute path (such as `/c/repos/wpsand/wpA`), then run again...I get the same problem.  **However**, the error message still says that device with relative path `./wp-db` cannot be found.

Apparently the re-use of the shared volume named `wp_dbA` causes any newly specified path to be ignored.  The original `./wp-db` is what it will attempt to use.

Clue #2

If I revert back to a relative path, but change the name of the shared volume to "wp_dbB", I still get the same error.

Clue #3

This combines #1 and #2 above.  If I invent a new shared volume name, and use an absolute path, it works!  My container is launched successfully.  Unfortunately, 
 I'm no longer using the relative path I wanted.

Clue #4

Now that my container works, I `docker-compose down` and change the docker-compose file again.  I put the relative path back in, and "compose up". **It works!**

### Conclusion?

It looks like relative paths simply don't work.  But I've been seeing docker-compose files posted online using this same shared volume relative path notation.  Perhaps it works for Docker, but not Docker on Windows?

Can anyone suggest a work-around?

### Update!

I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41948232/docker-compose-wont-find-pwd-environment-variable) that very nearly has a relative-path work-around.  I updated my compose file to use the `${PWD}` notation, and launched it from my Git Bash shell.  Now I got this error:

```
$ docker-compose up -d
Creating wpa_db_1        ... error
Creating wpa_db_1        ...

ERROR: for wpa_db_1  Cannot create container for service db: error 
while mounting volume with options: type='none'
device='C:/repos/wpsand/wpA/wp-db' o='bind': no such file or directory

ERROR: for db  Cannot create container for service db: error while 
mounting volume with options: type='none' device='C:/repos/wpsand/wpA/wp-db'
o='bind': no such file or directory
Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

That almost worked!  If only the `${PWD}` had expanded into a Linux mount notation (`/c/repos/wpsand/wpA/wp-db`)!

Comment: I'm having very similar issues on Docker for Windows. I tend to find that putting in a relative path rather than a shared volume name does work, but relative paths for a volume under the volumes section does not. Not sure why

Answer (score 6):

./ syntax worked for me for win 10 environment.

```
volumes:
  - ./mdata/:/data/db/
  - ./logs/:/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
  - ./mongod.cfg:/etc/mongod.conf.orig
```

Comment: That is strange. For me it was the relative path regardless if I opened with `./`. When I changed to `-v ${PWD}/local-relative:/remote/path` it worked.